# Get metadata of file present on dropbox before downloading in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox Api to display the list of files and folders present on it.. User can download file and view it..

I am downloading file every time .. but now i want to download file only if it is modified..
I can get date when file was updated in its metadata LastModifiedDate..

I have displayed all files in tableview  and at the time of display all files i am getting metadata of all files in following function i have mentioned. And if after displaying all list any file get change I will not get latest file..I am getting the latest LastModifiedDate after file gets download..

Following method gets called when file download is complete:

```
- restClient:loadedMetadata:
```

Is there any way by which i can get it before it starts downloading? Is there any method of dropbox api which gives metadata of file before download?

If anybody wants further explanation then please let me know..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Caching policies should be your friends, as far as the server is configured to support ETag.

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

[short guide](http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/HttpCondGet)